# Do We Know with Reasonable Certainty Where Goshen was Located?

Tags: israel, jacob, joseph, ancient-egypt

It is my understanding that after Joseph presented Jacob to Pharaoh, the king gave the Hebrews (Jacob and the rest of his party) some very fertile land (Goshen) in which to dwell by themselves. It seems that Egyptians held people who were shepherds in abomimation.

QUESTION: Do we have a good idea of where exactly Goshen was located; or is the exact site pretty much conjecture?